# Get all SimpleMemberAccessExpressions from SyntaxTree

Tags: c#, roslyn

The picture shows an example of a attribute of the kind SimpleMemberAccessExpression.

Is it possible to extract all SimpleMemberAccessExpressions from the SyntaxTree?

[image]

Comment: `syntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot().DescendantNodesAndSelf().Where(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression))`. Just to be clear, what did you try so far?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeAlexandria thanks, well I got this point   var memberAccess = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes(descendIntoTrivia: true)
                            .OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>()
                            .Where(m => m.Kind() == SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression).ToList();

Comment: and I was hoping that I could extract information about the object which the method belongs to. So in this case when GetClient is called it is part of a external dll and I actually want to know that this method belongs to this dll. Is this possible?

Comment: if you have a `IMethodSymbol` for `GetClient` and you want to determine that the invoking **signature** is from an external library – yes, it's possible: `methodSymbol.ContainingAssembly?.Identity.Name.Equals("assembly")`. But you cannot determine what a method will be invoked for the current receiver by the current signature without any extra analysis logic.